# TOP 10 rows in ORACLE when query contains GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select top 10 rows from the following query ?

```
select dim_product.PRODUCT_NAME, sum(units_sold * (revenue - cost)) 
from FT_SALES 
INNER JOIN dim_product 
ON ft_sales.prod_dwh_id = dim_product.product_dwh_id
group by dim_product.PRODUCT_NAME
order by 2 desc;
```

--- I tried the suggestion to use ROWNUM.

without ROWNUM I get the following results

Super Soft Bulk - 2 Litres  48223,5
Super Soft - 1 Litre    38842,16
Super Soft - 500ml  32879,29
Detafast Stain Remover - 100ml  29382
Detafast Stain Remover - 800ml  27336
Detafast Stain Remover - 200ml  24516
Pure Soft Detergent - 500ml 21147
Pure Soft Detergent - 250ml 20675,6
Pure Soft Detergent - 100ml - extra 19693,5
Pure Soft Detergent - 200ml 17563,74
Super Soft - 250ml  17430
Super Soft - Product Sample -2647,8

When added ROWNUM like that:

```
select dim_product.PRODUCT_NAME, sum(units_sold * (revenue - cost)) 
from FT_SALES 
INNER JOIN dim_product 
ON ft_sales.prod_dwh_id = dim_product.product_dwh_id
where ROWNUM<=10
group by dim_product.PRODUCT_NAME
order by 2 desc ;
```

I get the results:

Super Soft - 500ml  670,08
Pure Soft Detergent - 100ml - extra 597
Pure Soft Detergent - 200ml 338,3
Detafast Stain Remover - 100ml  246
Detafast Stain Remover - 200ml  213
Super Soft - 1 Litre    179,64

so it is not a solution in my case.

Comment: Is this to save time just fetching or doing the group by itself?

Comment: I just dont want 12 rows. I only need 10. It is not related to saving time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When selecting using `rownum` in Oracle, you need to use a subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select dim_product.PRODUCT_NAME, sum(units_sold * (revenue - cost)) 
      from FT_SALES INNER JOIN
           dim_product 
           ON ft_sales.prod_dwh_id = dim_product.product_dwh_id
      group by dim_product.PRODUCT_NAME
      order by 2 desc
     ) p
where rownum <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROWNUM <= 10 along with your query.

Answer (score 1):

Rownum only returns the specified rows, as they are initially retrieved by your query.

In your example, applying rownum to the query as you have returns the first ten rows the query fetches, and *then* orders them. Notice that your 10 returned results are indeed ordered as they should be, they are just not the 10 items you wanted.

To achieve a top ten list as you intended you must first perform your query, order the results as you want them, and *then* apply the rownum. This can be accomplished by turning your initial query into a subquery wrapped in an outer query which applies the rownum condition.

In general this looks something like:

```
select [whichever fields you need]
from (
      [query which collects and then sorts desired data]    
)
where rownum [is less than, greater than, equal to, or whatever else you need it to be]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in the another select and filter by rownum.

`SELECT * FROM (...) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10`

Comment: it doesn't mention the need for subquery

Comment: Okay :) I should be more clear next time. Though that *wrap it in the another select* will explain the idea :) In other words, I've wrote just the same select, just hid your inner select by the (...) dots